# When making a GET request to Axios for one item, the object returns null

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I can confirm that I can get all of the items but for whatever reason when I target a specific ID it returns null
 Inside my controller

```js
export function getCourse(id) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/courses/${id}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      dispatch({
        type: GET_COURSE,
        payload: response.data.course
      })
      console.log(response.data)
    })
  }
}
```

Inside the action creator

```js
exports.getCourse = function(req, res) {
  Course.findOne({ cuid: req.params.cuid }).exec((err, course) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
     return res.json({ course });
  });
};
```

Inside my routes

```js
router.route('/courses/:cuid').get(CourseController.getCourse);
```

Inside the reducer...

```js
import { ADD_COURSE, GET_COURSES, GET_COURSE } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  coursename: [],
  _creator: {},
  courses: {},
  course: {}
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_COURSE:
      return {
        ...state,
        coursename: [...state.coursename, action.coursename],
        _creator: action._creator,
      };
    case GET_COURSES:
      return {
        ...state,
        courses: action.payload
      }
     case GET_COURSE:
     console.log(state.course)
      return {
        ...state,
        course: action.payload
      }
  }
  return state;
}
```

Finally, inside my component

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.getCourse(this.props.match.params.cuid));
    console.log(this.props.course, "Is this it")
  }
```

Comment: In other words, `course ` is empty inside `exports.getCourse`

Comment: @d-reaper I know for sure that exports.getCourses returns an object with all of the courses. Could it have something to do with how I'm passing in the id inside my component.

Comment: can you log action.payload and confirm that you are getting the correct data? Also how are you getting the correct data from the redux store to your component?

Comment: @d-reaper I log action.payload but it's just showing up as null. I'm not quite sure how to answer your second question. I have another function inside my controller called getCourses and that returns an array of courses. I dispatch my action creator inside my component and use mapStateToProps from there. The Id that I'm passing in to actions.getCourse seems to be correct as it's part of my URL and I grab it using this.props.match.params.cuid.

Comment: Ok, so the error is probably happening before dispatch. Can you log response.data above dispatch call in getCourse?

Comment: @D-reaper above the dispatch call in my action creator I console logged amd it returned { course: null }

Comment: In your getCourse controller, can you remove the return keyword and just do `res.status(200).json({ course })` and see if you get a something in response.data. Just throw an error in the code `if (err) { /* throw error here */ }` for now.

Comment: I'm receiving the same result

Comment: But couse in exports.getCourse returns an array right? Can you also make sure that you are using https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser?

Comment: I don't appear to be using body-parser within the controller but it didn't stop me from getting an array of all courses using getCourses(). course as far as I know simiply returns null for whatever reason. I appreciate the help and your effort but I'll try to see if another friend can take a look at it tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think you can send response as json without body-parser. Do try it though, I'm sure that is the problem.

Comment: @d-reaper It was much simpler than we thought. I simply had to replace cuid: req.params.cuid with _id: req.params.cuid and it works fine now